# ANN regression problem with high loss - Python Pandas

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I try to run an artificial neural network with 2 parameters in input that can give me the value of the command.

An example of the dataset in CSV file:

```
P1,P2,S
7.03,3.36,787.75
6.11,3.31,491.06
5.92,3.34,480.4
5.0,3.39,469.77
5.09,3.36,481.14
5.05,3.35,502.2
4.97,3.38,200.75
5.01,3.34,464.36
5.0,3.42,475.1
4.94,3.36,448.8
4.97,3.37,750.3
5.1,3.39,344.93
5.03,3.41,199.75
5.03,3.39,484.35
5.0,3.47,483.17
4.91,3.42,485.29
3.65,3.51,513.81
5.08,3.47,443.94
5.06,3.4,473.77
5.0,3.42,535.78
3.45,3.44,483.23
4.94,3.45,449.49
4.94,3.51,345.14
5.05,3.48,2829.14
5.01,3.45,1465.58
4.96,3.45,1404.53
3.35,3.58,453.09
5.09,3.47,488.02
5.12,3.52,451.12
5.15,3.54,457.48
5.07,3.53,458.07
5.11,3.5,458.69
5.11,3.47,448.13
5.01,3.42,474.44
4.92,3.44,443.44
5.08,3.53,476.89
5.01,3.49,505.67
5.01,3.47,451.82
4.95,3.49,460.96
5.14,3.42,422.13
5.14,3.42,431.44
5.03,3.46,476.09
4.95,3.53,486.88
5.03,3.42,489.81
5.07,3.45,544.39
5.01,3.52,630.21
5.16,3.49,484.47
5.03,3.52,450.83
5.12,3.48,505.6
5.13,3.54,8400.34
4.99,3.49,615.57
5.13,3.46,673.72,
5.19,3.52,522.31
5.11,3.52,417.29
5.15,3.49,454.97
4.96,3.55,3224.72
5.12,3.54,418.85
5.06,3.53,489.87
5.05,3.45,433.04,
5.0,3.46,491.56
12.93,3.48,3280.98
5.66,3.5,428.5
4.98,3.59,586.43
4.96,3.51,427.67
5.06,3.54,508.53
4.88,3.49,1040.43
5.11,3.52,467.79
5.18,3.54,512.79
5.11,3.52,560.05
5.08,3.53,913.69
5.12,3.53,521.1
5.15,3.52,419.24
5.12,3.56,527.72
5.03,3.52,478.1
5.1,3.55,450.32
5.08,3.53,451.12
4.89,3.53,514.78
4.92,3.46,469.23
5.03,3.53,507.8
4.96,3.56,2580.22
4.99,3.52,516.24
5.0,3.55,525.96
3.66,3.61,450.69
4.91,3.53,487.98
4.97,3.54,443.86
3.53,3.57,628.8
5.02,3.51,466.91
6.41,3.46,430.19
5.0,3.58,589.98
5.06,3.55,711.22
5.26,3.55,2167.16
6.59,3.53,380.59
6.12,3.47,723.56
6.08,3.47,404.59
6.09,3.49,509.5
5.75,3.52,560.21
5.11,3.58,414.83
5.56,3.17,411.22
6.66,3.26,219.38
5.52,3.2,422.13
7.91,3.22,464.87
7.14,3.2,594.18
6.9,3.21,491.0
6.98,3.28,642.09
6.39,3.22,394.49
5.82,3.19,616.82
5.71,3.13,479.6
5.31,3.1,430.6
6.19,3.34,435.42
4.88,3.42,518.14
4.88,3.36,370.93
4.88,3.4,193.36
5.11,3.47,430.06
4.77,3.46,379.38
5.34,3.39,465.39
6.27,3.29,413.8
6.22,3.19,633.28
5.22,3.45,444.14
4.08,3.42,499.91
3.57,3.48,534.41
4.1,3.48,373.8
4.13,3.49,443.57
4.07,3.48,463.74
4.13,3.46,419.92
4.21,3.44,457.76
4.13,3.41,339.31
4.23,3.51,893.39
4.11,3.45,392.54
4.99,3.44,472.96
4.96,3.45,192.54
5.0,3.48,191.22
5.25,3.43,425.64
5.11,3.41,191.12
5.06,3.44,422.32
5.08,3.44,973.29
5.23,3.43,400.67
5.15,3.44,404.2
6.23,3.46,383.07
6.07,3.37,484.3
6.17,3.44,549.94
4.7,3.45,373.43
5.56,3.41,379.33
5.12,3.45,357.51
5.87,3.42,349.89
5.49,3.44,374.4
5.14,3.44,361.11
6.09,3.46,521.23
5.68,3.5,392.98
5.04,3.44,406.9
5.07,3.42,360.8
5.14,3.38,406.48
4.14,3.56,362.45
4.09,3.48,421.83
4.1,3.48,473.64
4.04,3.53,378.35
4.16,3.47,424.59
4.07,3.47,366.27
3.53,3.59,484.37
4.07,3.51,417.12
4.21,3.49,2521.87
4.15,3.5,458.69
4.08,3.52,402.48
4.2,3.47,373.26
3.69,3.5,486.62
4.24,3.51,402.12
4.19,3.5,414.79
4.13,3.55,390.08
4.2,3.5,452.96
4.06,3.52,524.97
4.22,3.47,442.46
4.07,3.5,403.13
4.07,3.51,404.54
4.17,3.46,393.33
4.1,3.4,430.81
4.05,3.41,365.2
4.11,3.47,412.8
4.13,3.49,431.14
4.03,3.51,417.5
3.9,3.48,386.62
4.16,3.49,351.71
5.18,3.48,351.43
4.49,3.5,336.33
3.7,3.51,551.8
6.39,3.44,369.79
6.74,3.35,408.57
6.0,3.38,2924.54
6.61,3.36,449.27
4.91,3.42,361.8
5.81,3.43,470.62
5.8,3.48,389.52
4.81,3.45,403.57
5.75,3.43,570.8
5.68,3.42,405.9
5.9,3.4,458.53
6.51,3.45,374.3
6.63,3.38,406.68
6.85,3.35,382.9
6.8,3.46,398.47
4.81,3.47,398.39
8.3,3.48,538.2
```

The code :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')

concatenation = pd.read_csv('concatenation.csv')

X = concatenation.iloc[:, :2].values # 2 columns
y = concatenation.iloc[:, 2].values # 1 column

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)


from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs= 1000)
```

But I have a problem during the training, I have high loss, I can not understand why?

```
Epoch 1/1000
10/10 [==============================] - 1s 22ms/step - loss: 407736.7188 - mae: 431.3878 - val_loss: 269746.6875 - val_mae: 380.4598
Epoch 2/1000
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 407391.1875 - mae: 431.0146 - val_loss: 269452.0625 - val_mae: 380.0934
Epoch 3/1000
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 407016.3750 - mae: 430.5912 - val_loss: 269062.3125 - val_mae: 379.6077
Epoch 4/1000
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 406472.7188 - mae: 430.0183 - val_loss: 268508.0312 - val_mae: 378.9190
Epoch 5/1000
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 405686.1562 - mae: 429.1566 - val_loss: 267709.7812 - val_mae: 377.9213
...
```

I checked that I didn't have a null value, I standardized my X_train
I didn't touch the outputs and I am well in case of regression with the right optimizer and the right loss function... so I can't understand why

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info . In any case, how exactly do you define "high" here?

Comment: all stats including loss are steadily improving, so I would say it works as expected, high loss at the very beginning doesn't mean anything, especially because the model is randomly initialized. Also, there are only two features, and the data is tabular, I would say neural networks are probably not your best choice

Comment: how to initiate the model in the best way then? What is the problem with tabular data? What other types of models do you advise me to test besides neural networks?